# How can I dynamically observe/change limits of a Autoscale group?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-auto-scaling

I want to modify the number of minimum/maximum/target instances of an autoscale group and see if there's any instance on from this autoscale group, all dynamically using the AWS SDK for Python. How can I do it?

I'm unable to find it from literature.

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html

Comment: write it as an answer, i'll accept it

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a link to the documentation you need to read.

Comment: Specifically, [get the current ASG config](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.describe_auto_scaling_groups), modify it as needed, and [update it](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.update_auto_scaling_group).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First verify your time is sync with aws:

```
sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

Read configuration:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('autoscaling')

response = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups(
    AutoScalingGroupNames=[
        'autoscaling_group_name',
    ]
)

print(response['AutoScalingGroups'][0]['MinSize'], response['AutoScalingGroups'][0]['MaxSize'], response['AutoScalingGroups'][0]['DesiredCapacity'], response['AutoScalingGroups'][0]['Instances'])
```

Set desired/min/max:

```
response = client.update_auto_scaling_group(
    AutoScalingGroupName='autoscaling_group_name',
    MinSize=123,
MaxSize=123,
DesiredCapacity=123,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I will help you by pointing out where you can find informaton about using AutoScaling and the **AWS SDK for Python**. Refer to the **AWS SDK Code Examples Code Library**.

[image]

This doc should be the reference point when you want to learn how to do tasks using a given AWS SDK.

See:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/auto-scaling_example_auto-scaling_Scenario_GroupsAndInstances_section.html